# Are there any late night bars at Milano Centrale?

Tags: transit, nightlife, milan

I'm reaching to Milan Centrale around **1 AM** and wonder if there is any bar/cafe/restaurant in the station open during late night hours? I have ~1-2 hours to wait till the airport shuttle.

If not, where is it safe to stay there till my shuttle arrives?

Comment: Have a look at https://www.milanocentrale.it/it/offertacommerciale/index/food  There do seem to be a lot of cafes but I could not immediately find one open that late.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Map over the mentioned places]

There are a lot of [options](https://goo.gl/maps/YJZnvzThbzs4d2j88):

- [Miniera d'Oro](https://goo.gl/maps/gMX2VLgj54z7ZeUP7), $$$$, **24/7**, just across the square from the centrale.
- [McDonald's](https://goo.gl/maps/4AZAWHwta9vK4rW38), open until **2 AM**. also just across the square from the centrale.
- [Monkey Cocktail Bar](https://goo.gl/maps/wyCJ6nm3BrecFzys7) is just *500 meter* away. They're usually open until **2 AM**.
- [Illumined Bar](https://goo.gl/maps/SvD6yac1Lhdb23iv8), gay bar, **24/7**. *500 meters* away.
- [Clover cocktail&grill](https://goo.gl/maps/7HNkghhSw4whma2K6), until **2 AM**, *600 meters* away.
- [Mordi & Fuggi](https://goo.gl/maps/u3S2aeTqxrrZ1fUr5), usually **24/7**, *600 meters* away.
- [Barba](https://goo.gl/maps/MuBg7ec4DXt299iv8), **1:30 AM**, *700 meters*.
- [Metropolis Lounge](https://goo.gl/maps/Eo6nhK3Rum4yNoRGA), **2 AM** again. *700 meters* away.
- [Bar Gatto](https://goo.gl/maps/uVzuuNYiuhjvZBgk8), also **2 AM**. About *900 meters* away.

On **Fridays and Saturdays** you also have:

- [Cocktail Bar Mogamo](https://goo.gl/maps/dx6k8HFvUFCdrFyGA), open until **2 AM**. Just *250 meters* away.
- [Bar Gluck](https://goo.gl/maps/ivGkfWVrjVqWNmmp6), doesn't close. 600 meters away.

---

*On top of these there are also numerous hotels nearby and they probably have bars and restaurants. You could take a walk and see if any of those are open.*

Answer (score 2):

In the area, you have:

- Cocktail Bar Mogamo - closes at midnight
- Monkey Cocktail bar - until 2am
- Bar Gatto - until 2am
- Bar Gluck - until midnight

Most of the cafes are closed after 8pm/9pm.

Source: [google maps search of open times](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Bar+Gluck/@45.4846713,9.1966829,15z/data=!4m12!1m6!2m5!1sbar!5m3!5m2!4m1!1i2!3m4!1s0x0:0xfe3c7e0a8afede02!8m2!3d45.4909965!4d9.2072511)